# Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: require is not defined (Electron + Next.js)

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, electron

I'm writing (Electron + Next.js) nextron desktop app.
I want to use contextIsolation=true , when i enabled contextIsolation=true and use import in renderer file like (import axios from 'axios') and something like that (third party package) it shows required is not define i think so its webpack error.
Need help to solve this issue
Error message:
[image: it through this error message]

**Preload.js**

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
//i try both import or require

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    setTitle: (title) => ipcRenderer.send('set-title', title)
})
```

**Renderer.js **

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Link from 'next/link';

//When i import axios here, it doesn't works
import axios from 'axios'
function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const setButton = document.getElementById('btn')
    const titleInput = document.getElementById('title')
    setButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const title = titleInput.value
      window.electronAPI?.setTitle(title)
    });
    data()
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Home - Nextron (with-typescript-tailwindcss)</title>
      </Head>
      Title: <input  id="title" />
      <button id="btn" type="button">Set</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

**Background.ts**

```
import { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import serve from "electron-serve";
import path from "path";
import { createWindow } from "./helpers";

const isProd: boolean = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

if (isProd) {
  serve({ directory: "app" });
} else {
  app.setPath("userData", `${app.getPath("userData")} (development)`);
}

(async () => {
  await app.whenReady();
  const mainWindow = createWindow("main", {
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration:true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  if (isProd) {
    await mainWindow.loadURL("app://./home.html");
  } else {
    const port = process.argv[2];
    await mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:${port}/home`);
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }
})();

ipcMain.on("set-title", (event, title) => {
  const webContents = event.sender;
  const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(webContents);
  win.setTitle(title);
  console.log(title, "title");
});
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  app.quit();
});
```

**NextConfig.js**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.target = 'electron-renderer';
      config.node = {
        __dirname: true,
      };
    }
   config.output.globalObject = 'this';
   return config;

  },
};
```

Comment: The code that is run in the browser is not a node environment. To access module importing, you need to import it in the main or preload JS file.

Comment: I'm hitting a similar problem where I'm loading in sentry via the next config